# Are protected questions used anywhere?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

Ok so a few months ago [Protected Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) were added to the system. However, to date the only one I've come across is the example question on Meta. Are any questions being made protected? I remember flagging a few questions as possible candidates for the feature(ones with a constant stream of "thanks" and "me too" answers) but nothing came of it.

Is the protected question feature just something put up on the shelf for a rainy day or are moderators actively using this feature?

Comment: See this [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/can-we-have-a-isprotected-search-operator).

Comment: Just saw one for the 1st time, http://serverfault.com/questions/5221/64-bit-cisco-vpn-client-ipsec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly better version of the query, sorted by viewcount

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/330/posts-with-many-thank-you-answers-ordered-by-views

Comment: Thx fr that. Great →.

Answer (score 1):

The old questions linked in *[Questions with lots of “Thank you” answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34464/questions-with-lots-of-thank-you-answers)* got protected when the feature was created, but I'm not sure if it has been use much since. Some new candidates to clean up and protect for the same reasons could be found with the [according database query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/329/posts-with-many-thank-you-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but this isn't a bad idea for the "Hidden Features" questions being discussed here in another topic.

Comment: If the rep threshold were, say, 500, then I might agree.  But I think that a requirement of just 10 rep is way too low to solve that particular problem...