# No diamond icon for moderators in protected question moderator tool

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, protected-questions

There is no diamond icon displayed for the moderator accounts in the [protected question 10k tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions?filter=month) page.

[image: protected question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done:

[image: Screenshot of page 17 of the Protected Questions tool, when sorted by the "Protected On" column, ascending]

[Made a few other changes as well.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304301/can-we-have-a-better-way-to-look-at-protected-questions-in-the-10k-tools/332595#332595)