# Retain the selected option with sorting type in protected question moderator tool when navigating between option tabs

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, protected-questions

Recently the UI for the [10k tools - protected question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions?filter=all) page is [updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332594/312043).
In the current UI, when navigating between the options tab (**all/month/week/day**) the selected column and its sort type is not retained.

For example: If I selected [month option with Question title descending order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions?filter=Month&sortColumn=Question&sortDirection=Descending) and navigating to **all** or **week** or **day** option, I'm expecting the Question title option selected with the descending sorting order. Instead of that for every option change it reset to "PROTECTED ON" with descending order.

Can be this selection option retained when navigating between the option tabs?