# Protected questions page has broken experience

Tags: discussion, bug, review, user-interface

Protected questions view has broken experience in mobile browser, which makes reviewing difficult.

**Browser**: Chrome

**Mobile**: iPhone 12

[image]

Comment: The dark mode tab is specific to Stack Overflow, thus off-topic here, but has also been reported countless times. [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4642212) already mentions that various tabs still need to be replaced by new dark-mode-aware components. The actual bug seems to be that the protected questions table isn’t responsive. Please tag this [tag:10k-tools] and not [tag:review], as this page is part of the 10k reputation tools, but not review queues. Oh, and the title could also benefit from more details.

Comment: Also, [Can we have a better way to look at protected questions in the 10K tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332595/289905) says that the responsiveness should be okay. On Firefox Nightly 85.0a1, Android, it works fine: the table occupies the full width and can be scrolled in either dimension, and the screen can be tilted to landscape mode.

Comment: Did you disable responsiveness? If so, that's the problem. Enable it and it should be fine. Otherwise, please mention it in the question as well.